# Resizing base64 image does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, canvas, base64

I tried many different ways, but in Firefox, when I resize the first time, it returns a blank image:

```
function imageToDataUri(img, width, height) {
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 canvas.width = width;
 canvas.height = height;
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
 setTimeout(function () {
   cursorimg = canvas.toDataURL();
 }, 500);
}
```

This is my function and I call it like this:

```
cursorImage.onload = function(){
  imageToDataUri(cursorImage, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Is your image loaded when the code first executes? (the image will have an onload event)

Comment: my image is cursorImage and I have calling function on onload, so it should be loaded

Comment: Whoops, my bad. What does the console say the canvas width/height are directly before the draw image call?

Comment: nothing, width and height is setted and I get only blank image with width and height which I sent

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue as you, and the issue disappeared when I created the canva outside the "onload" callback, like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
cursorImage.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    cursorimg = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

I'm still a beginner in JavaScript, I can't explain why it worked...